# How to set quality video on youtube api

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

how to set quality playback on Youtube api
because setPlaybackQuality does not woking after 2019

i try to setPlaybackQuality does not woking
i want to set video playback 1080p before play video
playerInfo.id.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');